# Why is libcurl returning a "0" after the JSON response string?

Tags: c++, json, libcurl

I'm trying to upload an image to the imgur API. I tried with the postman REST client and it returns exactly what I want. When I use libcurl in C++, it returns this:

```
{"data":{"id":"NsmDwZN","title":null,"description":null,"datetime":1494462656,"type":"image\/png","animated":false,"width":28,"height":22,"size":336,"views":0,"bandwidth":0,"vote":null,"favorite":false,"nsfw":null,"section":null,"account_url":null,"account_id":0,"is_ad":false,"in_most_viral":false,"tags":[],"in_gallery":false,"deletehash":"...","name":"","link":"..."},"success":true,"status":200}
0
```

Where is that 0 coming from?

Here is my main POST code:

```
int postToImgur(std::string file)
{
    curl_global_cleanup();

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    // Init winsock stuff
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    // Get curl handle
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
    struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;

    if (curl) {
        curl_formadd(&formpost, &lastptr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "image", CURLFORM_FILE, file.c_str(), CURLFORM_END);
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Expect:");
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Authorization: Client-ID bea02xxxxxaf4");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.imgur.com/3/image");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            MessageBox(NULL, _T("Could not upload image. Please check your internet connection."), _T("Error"), NULL);
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_formfree(formpost);
        curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And in my write_callback function I simply do:

```
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
CStringA responseStringA(ptr);
OutputDebugStringA((LPCSTR) responseStringA);
```

And it outputs a "0". This is breaking my parsing and I'm having to manually delete the 0 but it seems kinda sketch to have to do that. Any suggestions on where I could be getting this 0 from?

Comment: Your code doesn't show where `ptr` (which populates `responseString`) is being defined or assigned.

Comment: Sorry updated code. It's passed in by curl to the callback function.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to inspect the string at `ptr` before you call `OutputDebugStringA`? Why are you using `CStringA` anyway, as `OutputDebugStringA` accepts a raw `char*` value.

Comment: Your code doesn't correctly handle `\0` (null) values in the response, because you're using a null-terminated string when the documentation for libcurl states the size of the buffer that `ptr` points to is equal to `size * nmemb`. It's possible that the `0` is in garbage memory and you're reading beyond `ptr + ( size * nmemb )` which is the upperbound of the response.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was under the assumption that CStringA would take care of the null values when I pass it the char *ptr? That was my reasoning for using CStringA.

Comment: The `CString` constructor that accepts a single `char*` argument states it is for null-terminated strings. If you still want to use `CString` then you should use the constructor that accepts a length argument too.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused now. I thought you said the error was coming from not handling the null value correctly? If the constructor accepts a single null-terminated `char*` (which `ptr` seems to be), wouldn't that be what I want?

Comment: No, because if `ptr` does not point to a null-terminated value then `CString` will keep on reading memory past the length of the buffer until it encounters a null value.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I posted I solution that I think addresses that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dai for the help. Libcurl does not pass the `ptr` in the response as a null-terminated char array. That was where my error was coming from. I think I have a working solution to create another (bigger) char array, copy the previous one over, and set the last character to the null terminating symbol.

Please check my solution and let me know if I'm messing up strncpy somehow:

```
size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{

    char * responseString = new char[nmemb + 1]();
    strncpy(responseString, ptr, nmemb);
    responseString[nmemb] = '\0';
    OutputDebugStringA(responseString);
    ...
}
```

Comment: 1. You aren't calling `free` after calling `malloc`. 2. Using `free` and `malloc` is not idiomatic C++, use `new[]` with a RAII smart-pointer instead. 3. You're calculating `newSize` incorrectly (it's `size*nmemb`, not `size*(nmemb+1)`). 4. You should pass `newSize` to `strncpy` instead of `nmemb`. 5. You're not setting the null-terminator at the correct index (it should be at `[newSize-1] = '\0'`).

Comment: Just finished a semester of learning C... that's all that's in my head. I had a few questions:

1. Why would strncpy take `size*nmemb`? The third parameter is the number of chars to copy, right? So that would be `nmemb` if I understand it correctly. 

2. I made the array one bigger than the source, copied over all elements of the source to destination, and then set the last element of the destination ((nmemb + 1) -1) which is just `nmemb`. Wouldn't I set that to the null terminator?